# How to define variables in a DRY way

Tags: serverless-framework

Let's say I have function that writes to a S3 bucket. So the bucket name is clearly a "variable" that should not be hard-coded into the function (might be different buckets for dev vs. prod, for example).

Now, I need to use the bucket name in at least two places if I want the function to be able to access it:

1. In the IAM policy of the function (allowing access to the bucket).
2. In the function itself.

For #1 I can use a variable, and refer to the variable in the IAM policy defined in `s-module` (or whatever it's called in v0.4 :).

For #2 I can use an env var, whose value I could then access in the function code during runtime.

But I certainly don't want to have to define the variable twice (once with `sls env set` and once in the `s-variables` file). That's not very DRY. However, I don't see a way to refer to variables when defining envars, or vice versa.

How could I define the bucket name in just one place?

Comment: So far I've taken to doing exactly that:  duplicating template variables alongside env variables. While one doesn't edit yet, I'd love a plugin that automates that process as part of the env declaration process.

Comment: An ability to refer to envars from variables, or vice versa would also do the trick. Heck, the ability to refer to actual process envvars in either of them would suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of [Serverless v0.5](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/releases/tag/v0.5.0), this is pretty easy.  Environment variable handling blends *Serverless Project Variables*.  You define the Project variables in `_meta/variables/...` in a per-stage per-region way; for instance, in `s-variables-dev-useast1.json`:

```
{
    "foo_bucket": "com.example.foo-bucket"
}
```

Then, in the `s-function.json` file(s) where that bucket is used, you define the environment variables that function needs... and *reference* the Project Variable in a template-like way:

```
"environment": {
    "BUCKET": "${foo_bucket}"
}
```

It will then appear just like any other environment variable; so in Node:

```
console.log("The Bucket: " + process.env.BUCKET); 
// prints "The Bucket: com.example.foo-bucket"
```

So far the [Serverless docs](http://docs.serverless.com/docs) haven't caught up with this change, but I expect they should soon-ish.

Comment: @AssafLavie could you please accept answer from Peter Wagener as it is correct solution on your question?