# serverless variables in local tests

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

serverless offers a nice workflow for using variables in both the runtime function code as well as in the AWS configuration of Lambda functions and API Gateway routing. This is described at http://docs.serverless.com/docs/templates-variables and [How to define variables in a DRY way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382007/how-to-define-variables-in-a-dry-way).

I am having trouble figuring out how to assign variables when I am testing my Lambda functions locally using `sls function run -s stage`. The function runs fine when I run the test on Lambda by including the `-d` option, but it fails without it because a necessary variable hasn't been assigned. serverless provides these messages:

```
Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: region  
Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: appEnv
```

I am using DRY variables as described in link [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382007/how-to-define-variables-in-a-dry-way). Specifically:

s-variables-aguldman-useast1.json:

```
{
  "appEnv": "qa"
}
```

functions/fn1/s-function.json:

```
{
...
  "environment": {
    "NODE_ENV": "${appEnv}"
  }
...
}
```

functions/fn1/handler.js:

```
...
var foo = process.env.NODE_ENV;
...
```

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have to do a bit of guessing here because I'm lacking some info from your question. So I will assume that:

- that you are trying to output a variable called region
- that you have a s-function.json file that has this in it:

  `"environment": {
      "myEnvironmentVar":"${myEnvironmentVar}"
    }`
- that you are trying to access the content of the region variable using this code in you lambda function:
  `process.env.myEnvironmentVar;`

if this is the warning you are getting:

`Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: region`

If this is the case then the problem is that you haven't defined this variable any of the these two files:

- _meta/variables/s-variables-common.json
- _meta/variables/s-variables-stage.json

Also if you add the value in s-variables-common.json and then also add it to s-variables-stage.json then s-variables-stage.json will override the value of s-variables-common.json

Comment: Right, right. Sorry about the lousy question. I just improved it, and (predictably) in the process of doing so was able to answer my own question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I add the `-r us-east-1` option to `serverless function run` then it works fine. Interestingly, serverless doesn't need the -r option when it is run remotely (if there is a single region in the project) but does when run locally.

To summarize:

```
serverless function run -s stage -r us-east-1
```

successfully reads variables from the appropriate s-variables file, but

```
serverless function run -s stage
```

does not. In contrast,

```
serverless function run -s stage -d
```

works fine without a region being explicitly specified, presumably because I only have one region in my project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all run following command to create your stage/regions's variables json file in _meta folder

```
sls stage create
```

then provide your stage name and the region(you have to provide your amazon access key and the secret key). Then the following json file will be created.

```
_meta/variables/s-variables-{your_region}-{your_stage}.json
ie. _meta/variables/s-variables-us-east-1-dev.json
```

If you want to add the variable manually you can do it as follows. Those variables will be added to above s-variables-{your_region}-{your_stage}.json file

```
sls variables set
```

and then give the key and the value or in one line as follows

```
sls variables set -k appEnv -v dev
```

Hope this helps.